# Detect emoji in plain text using PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to change expressions in the form of:

```
[E-01] - [E-02] - [E-03] - [E-04] ...
```

to

```
<img src = "E-XX.png">
```

How can I do that?

#### Input

```
$message = "Hello [E-02] World [E-01]";
```

#### Desired Output

```
Hello <img src="E-02.png"> World <img src="E-01.png">
```

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: I just need to identify the beginning of the [E-] form and replace with preg_match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preg_replace is your friend:

```
$message = "Hello [E-02] World [E-01]";
$replaced = preg_replace('/\[(E-\d\d)\]/', '<img src="/assets/images/emoji/$1.png" height="20" width="20" />', $message);
echo $replaced;
```

**Output:**

```
Hello <img src="/assets/images/emoji/E-02.png" height="20" width="20" /> World <img src="/assets/images/emoji/E-01.png" height="20" width="20" />
```

Comment: Thanks You  friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
function emoji($message){
            for($e=1; $e <= 60; $e++){
                $e    = (($e < 10) ? '0' . $e : $e);
                $name = 'E-' . $e;
                $message = str_replace('[' . $name . ']', ' <img src="/assets/images/emoji/' . $name. '.png" height="20" width="20" /> ', $message);
            }
            return $message;
        }
```